# What is the keycode for the open curly brace {

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror, keycode

I'm creating a code-mirror instance with an autocomplete system that will activate on any key press. But whenever you type: { the auto complete still appears even though there is an if statement blocking key code 219 from showing the autocomplete. The reason why I want to stop the { from opening the autocomplete menu is that the user would usually press Enter to go down a line but it puts in the suggestion from the autocomplete.
I've already tried using charCode but that didn't work.

here is my code:

```js
editor.on("keyup", function (cm, event) {
            if (!cm.state.completionActive && event.keyCode != 13 && event.keyCode != 219) { 
                CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete(cm, null, {completeSingle: false});
            }
        });
```

I want it to not open the autocomplete menu in codemirror whenever the user presses {

Comment: If you aren't sure what it is either look it up on web or just log `event.keyCode` to console and press that key and see what it shows in console

Comment: Yes I have done that but it has the same output as [

Comment: Note that adding a different listener won't override previous ones that are set by the api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by replacing `keyCode` with `charCode` and changing the event to `keypress`.

```js
editor.on("keypress", function (cm, event) {
            if (!cm.state.completionActive && event.charCode != 13 && event.charCode != 123) {
                CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete(cm, null, {completeSingle: false});
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `&&` with Enter key and `{` so it will never go into the if condition

```
editor.on("keyup", function (cm, event) {
        if (!cm.state.completionActive && (event.keyCode != 13 || event.charCode != 219)) { 
            CodeMirror.commands.autocomplete(cm, null, {completeSingle: false});
        }
    });
```

Comment: No, you are in the condition you are saying `Enter` && `{` should be pressed, it should be an `||` because you can't press `Enter and {` at the same time, it's two different events